# incron on Ubuntu - bash script called by incrontab - dollar parentheses $(command) command substitutions fail

Tags: bash, ubuntu, incron

I have a bash script that runs fine from the command line, but when it's called from [incrontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) the substitutions fail. The script runs, but the commands in $(...) fail :(

My incrontab -e :

```
/home/kelly/summer IN_CREATE /bin/bash /usr/share/summerwear/notify.sh
```

in my script (notify.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash
swimwear=$(grep -i "swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
echo "The swimwear request is $swimwear" > /home/kelly/log.txt
```

The contents of my log file then look like this:

The swimwear request is

..

An example of the incoming inquiry.txt file:

request 1 - swimsuit - blue - daytime - informal

request 2 - gown - black - nighttime - formal

..

Setting the PATH and SHELL from incron.conf doesn't seem to make a difference.

I have also tried variations of stuff like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
swimwear=$(grep -i "swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
echo "swimwear equals $swimwear" > /home/kelly/log.txt
```

And every combination I can think of:

```
swimwear=$(grep -i "swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
swimwear=$("grep -i swimsuit /home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
swimwear=$(grep -i 'swimsuit' "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
swimwear=$(grep -i swimsuit "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
swimwear=$(grep -i $("swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt"))
swimwear=$( $(grep -i "swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt"))
```

..and endless combinations of single-quotes, double quotes, no-quotes, etc.
...as well as specifying the grep PATH:

```
swimwear=$(/bin/grep -i "swimsuit" "/home/kelly/summer/inquiry.txt")
```

(etc.)...
There are several posts dealing with setting and/or specifying the PATH and SHELL for cron jobs, crontab, etc., but I'm not seeing a whole lot of information out there regarding "incrontab" specifically.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: try logging errors in the script by adding `exec 1>/home/kelly/log-output.txt 2>/home/kelly/log-errors.txt` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Wow, thanks @GordonDavisson for this answer! It eventually helped me solve the problem, which was this:
My script began running as soon as the the file was created, but before the data actually appeared.
$(grep..) was working all along, but it took a couple of milliseconds for any data to be uploaded.
The solution: in my "incrontab -e", I changed:
IN_CREATE
to:
IN_CLOSE_WRITE

Thanks again for your reply! Marking as solved.